# Olympiad problem

Tags: combinatorics

There is an integer in each square of an $8 \times 8$ chessboard. In one move, you may choose any $4 \times 4$ or $3 \times 3$ square and add $1$ to each integer of the chosen square. Can we always get a table with each entry divisible by (a) $2$, (b) $3$?

I think finding answer revolves around finding an invariant. 
Let $S$ = sum of all the integers in the square - sum of integers of third row - sum of integers of sixth row 
Then $S \bmod 2$ is an invariant. 
Similarly $S \bmod 3$ will be an invariant if instead of integers of 3rd and 6th rows ,
We subtract integers of 4th and 8th rows.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You are more likely to get a response if you show that you've made an effort.

Comment: Ok. I will update my attempt. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: One way to start is to work with a $1\times 8$ board and choosing $1 \times 3$ or $1 \times 4$ rectangles to add to.  If you can't do this, you can't do the whole board.  If you can, you might learn something about how that informs you how to deal with the other direction.

Comment: Your invariants are good choices.  Now compute them for the solved board.  If the board doesn't start off with an acceptable value  for the invariant you can't solve it.  This doesn't prove that you can solve all boards that do satisfy this requirement, but you weren't asked about that.  In fact, there are a number of variations on your invariants that make requirements as well, but you have enough to answer the question negatively.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.